# AS3 Delete child node from XML by child value

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've got an XML with a structure like the following;

```
 <items>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>3006</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>458</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>78</item>
 </items>
```

How do I delete the item with the value 458. Just to clarify this, I don't know the index of that item, so simply calling delete items[index] won't do here.
I have to delete by value.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using e4x filtering and the possibilities of using function inside the filter you can delete the node you want :

- xml.item.(text()==value) will give you the node your are looking for
- valueOf() will give you the current node you are filtering
- delete will delete the node

so combining these infos you can do :

```
var xml:XML=<items>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>3006</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>458</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>78</item>
 </items>;

 function deleteValue(xml:XML, value:String):void{
   xml.item.((text()==value) && (delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()]));
 }

 deleteValue(xml, "458");

 trace(xml.toXMLString());
```

Comment: Works... But makes me want to cry. For readability I would have stuck with a for..loop

Comment: Given that I access child components of my initial XML, my source XML for this would be an XMLList (sorry I just realised that), thus I need to convert my XMLList to XML first, which gives me some problems.

Answer (score 7):

this should solve it. Btw this will delete all direct chilren with name "item" that have value 458.

```
delete xml.(item == "458");
```

To delete recursively all children and subchildren that have name "item"  and value 458 use:

```
delete xml..(item == "458");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an exception saying that delete doesn't work on XMLList. I had to do: delete handXML.tile.(@type == boostType)[0];

Comment: @DoomGoober This answer is based on this particular example, If you have a different xml structure for sure it will not work. Please have a look at the example provided inside the question. Also are you sure you are not deleting only the first set of titles ?

Comment: My comment wasn't clear. But, delete xml.(item == "458"); won't work either! xml.(item == "458") evaluates to an XMLList. delete doesn't work on XMLList, only on XML itself. Thus, the only way to actually get an XML object is to use the indexer. delete xml.(item == "458")[0];